# Upper bounds on gaussian norm maxima, maximal inequality for 2-norm of chi-squared(m) distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I was reading Negahban(2012) "A Unified Framework for High-Dimensional Analysis of M-Estimators with Decomposable Regularizers", and in paragraph betwwen eq(45) and eq(46) basically claimed that tail bounds for $\chi^2$-variates satisfy below condition, which is

$E[max_{t=1,\dots,N}\Vert\epsilon_t\Vert_2]\leq\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{3\log(N)}$, where each $\epsilon_t$ is a standard Gaussian vector with m elements.

I think I understand where $\sqrt{m}$ term comes from, but couldn't use it to derive such maximal inequality.

I have studied similar maximal inequality for Gaussian maxima, but not sure with this chi-squared tail bound (or gaussian norm maxima). How can I verify this claim?

Comment: $||e_t||_2$ means $\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^m x_i^2}$ or  $\sum_{i=0}^m x_i^2$? If it means the first one, then you should write '"... claimed that tail bounds for $\chi$-variates satisfy ...  " and "... but not sure with this **chi** tail bound ...", right?

Comment: @NN2 The former one is I'm referring to, which was written on the original paper.

Comment: Perhaps the inequality $(7)$ of http://www.public.asu.edu/~gdasarat/files/maxGaussians.pdf may help. Notice that 
$$|\epsilon||_2 = \sqrt{\chi_2(k)} =  \sqrt{\Gamma\left( \frac{k}{2},\frac{1}{2}  \right))} $$ in distribution, and
$$E(\max |\epsilon||_2)  = E(\sqrt{\max Y_i}) \le E^2(\max Y_i) $$
with $Y_i =\chi_2(k) = \Gamma\left( \frac{k}{2},\frac{1}{2}  \right) $ in distribution

Comment: @NN2 Thank you!, could we use Jensen inequality(Concave version) so that
$$E(\sqrt{\max Y_i})\leq\sqrt{E(\max Y_i)}$$

Comment: We can use the Jensen's inequality here. But I don't know whether the result in your question can be obtained.